# foreach CheckBoxList always not checked

Tags: c#, web-controls, checkboxlist, listitem, asp.net-webcontrol

So basically, I'm aiming to just do a simple loop that, upon submission, checks to see if a bunch of boxes have been checked before continuing. I'd know how to do this in PHP or with MVC and all that, but I'm forced to use webcontrols by my boss.

Ergo, here we are.

Relevant code in Default.aspx

```
<div>
    <asp:CheckBoxList id="eligibilityreqs" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem value="item1" runat="server">I am great</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="item2" runat="server">I am amazing.</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="item3" runat="server">I completed EVERTHING</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="item4" runat="server">Pies are delicious</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="item5" runat="server">Oh man a fifth one</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
<p>
    <asp:Label Text="" id="finalmessage" runat="server" />
</p>
<div>
    <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" onclick="process" />
</div>
```

Default.aspx's codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace minor
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void process (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool valid = true;
            string debugtext = "";
            foreach (ListItem li in eligibilityreqs.Items) {
                if (!li.Selected) {
                    valid = false;
                    debugtext = debugtext + li.Selected;
                }
            }
            if (!valid) {
                finalmessage.Text = "There has been an error, please check all boxes." + debugtext;
            } else {
                string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
                using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString)) {
                    string sqlstring = "SELECT yum FROM pie_application LIMIT 1;";
                    using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand(sqlstring, con)) {
                        con.Open ();
                        string reader = Convert.ToString (com.ExecuteScalar ());
                        finalmessage.Text = reader;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For reference the output of debugtext is just false,false,false,false,false.

Comment: How, when and from where do you databind the `CheckBoxList`?

Comment: Lani, can you add this line above the `bool valid = true` and but a break point after this line and check to see if you get a List of checked items? `List<ListItem> items =  eligibilityreqs.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(n => n.Selected).ToList();`

Comment: I just noticed another potential problem I would change `string reader = Convert.ToString (com.ExecuteScalar ());` to `var reader = (string)com.ExecuteScalar();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known mono bug. For those interested, update mono or build it anyway assuming it works and then deploy.

Alternatively, just code better and avoid webcontrols entirely... If your boss allows you to.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that you databind the `CheckBoxList` even on postbacks. That would deselect all selected items.

So check the `IsPostBack` property.

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBindCheckBoxList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly Tim.but can't really tell anything without seeing the Page_Load and or other code in regards to how the Method is being called.. is it from a Button_Click..?...etc.. if so then your answer would be a valid / highly possibility as to what the problem is

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Yes, the method is called from the button(see aspx). My answer is just a guess because  OP is short on experience with ASP.NET. It's a common issue for newbies. Because he didn't post the page_load i assume that he doesn't know this property ;)

Comment: @Time Schmelter I totally agree.. I am not questioning your answer. I think that many do not understand the PostBack vs Button Clicks in a WinForms wish the OP would give some sort of Response or confirmation

Comment: She, actually. Let's not assume. And yes, I'm new to the webcontrol model. I've done MVC3 and I've done a ton of PHP. Not a huge fan of this "let's write all your HTML for you" webcontrol nastiness. Umm... That said, I'm not exactly sure on databinding x.x. Is there a particular reason the button click doesn't get me the submitted information of the list? If I were to get the value of simple text box, it works. One would imagine, since both have names and are being submitted in a form, that they both could be acquired equally easily.

Comment: @LaniAlden: If the code you posted is complete my answer doesn't help. I've just guessed that you're databinding the control(f.e. the selected items from database) from page_load. Since this event happens earlier in the page' life-cycle it would change the selection of the user with the old selection. That's why i've used the `Page.IsPostBack` property to determine if this is the first load or a postback.

Comment: My code is more or less complete. I've left things out like the irrelevant fields (generic textboxes, from which I can get data via things like phone.Text). However, the codebehind that I provided is, in fact, complete. Modified of course for privacy, but complete.

Comment: @LaniAlden: Then your code should work and actually it does(tested). If one checkbox is not selected you're getting to the error-part, i asume that this is desired.